# Searching laravel in multiple tables

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am quite new with Laravel and still learning. 
Love the application, but find it quite difficult 
to find the right way to make a search form.

I have two tables, table1 and table2. 
Their structure is something like this:

table1 = id | user_id | data
          1 | 1 | x
          2 | 2 | y

table2 = id | user_id | sex_id | data
          1 | 1         | 1         | a
          2 | 2         | 2         | b
          3 | 1         | 1         | c
          4 | 2         | 1         | d

Now I want to select all the data from table1 
where the user_id from table1 has the sex_id 1 in table2.

Would this be possible?
What would be the right way to select from multiple tables in Laravel?

Thank you, your input is highly appreciated.

Comment: You would do `join` of those tables, and filter by fields `table1.user_id` and `table2.sex_id`

Comment: Basically you would use [query join](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#joins)

Comment: Do you have Laravel eloquent `models`? if so, please post them. if not please create them with their relations, and then use `whereHas` method to get the data.

Comment: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-searchable this could help you

Comment: Thanks guys, your input really helped me, have updated the request with answer. Took me a while, but your input send me in the right way.

Answer (score 1):

Have made it work with the join function.

See example below;

```
 # gender search
        $get_pages = DB::table('d_pages')
            ->join('d_user_profiles', function($join) use($gender) {
                    $join->on('d_user_profiles.user_id', '=', 'd_pages.user_id');
                    $join->where('d_user_profiles.m_sex_id', '=', $gender);
            })
            ->select('d_pages.id', 'd_pages.user_id', 'd_pages.image_path')
            ->orderBy('d_pages.like_amount', 'desc')->get();
```